# iOS Barcode detection with Xamarin / Vision framework

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I want to detect bar codes using the new Vision API of iOS 11 with C# / Xamarin.

However, the *VNDetectBarcodesRequest* class of xamarin is abstract. Other request types, for example VNDetectRectanglesRequest are not.  Is this part of the framework not implemented in Xamarin or am I missing something here?

Basically I want to adapt the rectangle detection sample (https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monotouch/ios11/VisionRectangles/) to detect QR codes.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### **Update**: This bug is fixed, review [xamarin-macios/issues/3140](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/3140)

That is a **bug** in the Xamarin generated bindings as it is correctly bound **except** for the incorrectly applied `[Abstract]` attribute.

Note: I created a Github issue: [xamarin-macios/issues/3140](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/3140)

Since the binding otherwise is correct, you can work around by creating your own VNDetectBarcodesRequest subclass.

#### VNDetectBarcodesRequest Workaround

```
public class FixVNDetectBarcodesRequest : VNDetectBarcodesRequest
{
    public FixVNDetectBarcodesRequest(NSObjectFlag t) : base(t) { }

    public FixVNDetectBarcodesRequest(IntPtr handle) : base(handle) { }

    public FixVNDetectBarcodesRequest(VNRequestCompletionHandler completionHandler) : base(completionHandler) { }
}
```

Usage:

```
var detectBarcodesRequest = new FixVNDetectBarcodesRequest((request, error) =>
{
    //
});
```

#### Incorrect `VNDetectBarcodesRequest` binding:

```
[TV (11,0), Mac (10,13, onlyOn64: true), iOS (11,0)]
[Abstract]
[DisableDefaultCtor]
[BaseType (typeof (VNImageBasedRequest))]
interface VNDetectBarcodesRequest {

    [Export ("initWithCompletionHandler:")]
    [DesignatedInitializer]
    IntPtr Constructor ([NullAllowed] VNRequestCompletionHandler completionHandler);

    [Static]
    [Protected]
    [Export ("supportedSymbologies", ArgumentSemantic.Copy)]
    NSString [] WeakSupportedSymbologies { get; }

    [Static]
    [Wrap ("VNBarcodeSymbologyExtensions.GetValues (WeakSupportedSymbologies)")]
    VNBarcodeSymbology [] SupportedSymbologies { get; }

    [Protected]
    [Export ("symbologies", ArgumentSemantic.Copy)]
    NSString [] WeakSymbologies { get; set; }
}
```

re: [vision.cs#L156](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/blob/1690ccbc991ab59835f76a15ef510cd182259915/src/vision.cs#L156)